# How to prevent inheriting packages from parent node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, react-scripts

First I will give some context to the problem.

I am developing an npm library. Inside the project folder, I have another folder called "example", for testing the library. The structure looks like below.

```
|- node_modules/
|- src/ 
|- example/
|   |- node_modules/
|   |- src/
|   |- package.json
|- package.json
```

The root package.json has the dependency `babel-jest`. The example/package.json has the dependency `react-scripts`. When running `react-scripts start` inside example directory, it gives the following error,

[image: Error screenshot]

---

As far as I can understand, this is because, the package.json inside the example/ directory inherits *(not sure if this is the right term)* the dependencies of the root package.json.

That is, I can use a dependency installed in the root package.json, inside the src/ of the example/
This is convenient in some cases. But this is a blocker for my use case.

How can I prevent this behaviour? (without changing the directory structure)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, [Dan Abramov suggests](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1795#issuecomment-357445440) to use `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to work around this problem as there is no real fix.

Answer (score 0):

Two viable options are to either set a prefix or do some scripting to merge the two `node_modules` folders.

### Merging the two folders

```
PACKAGES=$(cat package.json | jq -r '.dependencies' | jq 'keys_unsorted' | jq -r '.[]')
for p in $PACKAGES; do
    # Check if the parent have it
    [[ ! -d "../../node_modules/$p" ]] && echo "$p directory exists!"

    # Check if the local path have it
    [...]
done
```

### Installing with prefix

```
npm install --prefix ./
```

Another thing to consider is if you are working in a application and use some other package. For some reason, that I don't fully understand I could not get it to work when using a workspace package unless that package was distributed on npm. But for some reason it did find it with using the equivalent of the --prefix flag in yarn.

```
yarn install --modules-folder node_modules
```